# Wrong coordinates after loading OSM to postgre

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, openstreetmap

After loading OSM data for whole Europe to postgres (Osm2pgsql) I'm trying to add them to Geoserver, but the coordinates are totally wrong. The SRS is correct (4326), but the coordinate values are oddly small.
Do you have any idea what i've made wrong? And how to change it?

[image]

More over the data is displayed not correctly. eg lines are not displayed as lines, but as squares, and other tables are the same (it looks more like some OSM data boundries). Does anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: What were the parameters for osm2pgsql when you first imported the data? I would also run `select * from public.geometry_columns;` in the database to confirm that the column is in fact your desired SRID.

Comment: As it was explain on some webpages (it is my first time trying add osm to geoserver)
osm2pgsql -c -d osm -U postgres -H localhost
-S file osm.pbf

Comment: how to you get osm.pbf file ?

Comment: @Anna I would recommend posting screenshots with interface language set to English, not Polish.

Comment: Looks like the coordinates have been rounded to some smaller values.